# iOS Login Screen For External Sqlite Server

Tags: mysql, ios, sqlite

Ok, so say I wanted to have a sign up form similar to the iOS apps of Facebook, Gmail, Dropbox etc. I don't mean I want to have the users be able to login using those services (although that would be nice) but I want to actually have something similar to a SQL server as the web service https://parse.com/ would use.

It seems like a great service and very easy to setup, but I would like to go the extra mile and take advantage of the servers I have available in the cloud to create my own custom version of the following. I understand that mySQL isn't very usable within the iOS development platform, however sqlite3 is. Say I've created my storyboard layout and I think I have an idea of what it is I would like to do. I just don't know what I need to do to achieve it! Essentially what would be ideal is to to create statistical models based on the combined data from all of the users.

Properties of the application:

I would like the users also to be able to go online and download the data they entered into the iOS app by importing it into excel. However it would be very important that I nor any other user could identify the source of the data. As most of my users are going to know of each other in real life. Think of the app as something to do with drag racing, and the users enter in there race results and information about their setup and then upload it to my server. It is very important that I cannot see which user the information derived from, but at the same time would like to access the data and retrieve a list of the users and their respective emails!

User Interface of application:

Here is a screenshot of what the storyboard ideally might look like. Nothing is linked together yet these are just the screens that I originally had in mind! I'm not asking for anyone to give me any serious help as I want to do it on my own, I just need the resources in order to do it myself. It seems as if there is nothing online that could explain how the website parse's framework was created!

STORYBOARD 1:   [i39.tinypic.com/fbz7n6.jpg](http://i39.tinypic.com/fbz7n6.jpg)

STORYBOARD 2:   [i41.tinypic.com/dewoau.jpg](http://i41.tinypic.com/dewoau.jpg)

**How can I make a service similar to parse (JSON format) by using my own server in the cloud?**

Comment: You need to split this up into smaller questions. You also need to keep in mind that the server technology and the client technology for data storage don't need to be the same in any way - only the interface between them is important. IIRC Parse.com uses JSON to store things behind the scenes.

Comment: Ok, if by server I'm assuming you mean the web app, and by client you mean the iOS device. What would the interface be defined as then? I'm taking a guess as to say something similar to sqlite or the core application data? Then the client sends information to the sqlite service which expects the data in JSON format. After the sqlite service receives the data it then sends it to the web application? While the whole time the data format remains unmodified and remains in JSON format. Then you can literally parse the JSON data almost identically to "parse"? Am I getting this right?

Comment: At no point does SQLite expect JSON. They are completely unrelated. Only some wrapper code can integrate them. JSON would be the transport serialisation of the data. SQL is for the data storage at either end (client and server). JSON is for transport. (at least in what you're thinking, because the JSON could be saved to disk in a file and used for storage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL on the server and SQLite on the client (preferably wrapped in Core Data) without any issue. The two shouldn't directly interact or have any knowledge of each other. Because the server will present an API for the client to use. And that API should divulge no information about the internal setup of the server.

For the API, think about a RESTful interface, probably implemented with JSON.

This caters for all of your uploading and downloading capability.

Your other things are built around this. You have good intentions for keeping the data anonymous - but that is a facet of what you send and how you structure the data storage in the server.

Finally, doing it yourself will be error prone and take a long time. Creating a Parse.com account and configuring the database will be relatively error free and will take very little time. What do you make money from? (hint: leveraging the work of others).

Comment: Thank you! However, It still helps to at least understand the framework in which I would be using a little better before I trust a third party with storing my data. Thanks for the helpful response! I think I'm going to do a few Core Data tutorials from raywenderlich.com before I make such a crucial decision in the application. After all it is very important to stand on top of the shoulders of others, but at the same time I want to understand and make use of all of my resources! Also if you have came across any good Core Data / Sqlite tutorials that have helped you in the past? Thanks!

Comment: Ray Wenderlich site should be a good place to start. Just keep in mind: 1. Separate your concerns between the client and server. 2. Use high level API over low if you have the choice (i.e. Core Data instead of SQLite directly).

Comment: Will keep in mind, thank you!